# CSS позиционирование при overflow

Tags: css

Если сделать overflow:hidden, по умолчанию прокручиваемый контент будет пристыкован к верхнему и левому краю прокручиваемого блока. Как сделать, чтобы он пристыковывался к нижнему?

Зачем нужно: хочу сделать дерево с эффектом, при раскрытии элемента которого, подкатегории будут плавно "выезжать" из-под родительского элемента. Если это сделать с обычными настройками (т.е. пристыковано к верху), получится "раскрывание" вместо "выезжания".

Comment: Без примера не очень понятно, чего вы хотите. Но чтобы элемент выезжал, лучше анимировать transform от translateY(-100%) к translateY(0). А что до позиционирования - position: absolute и bottom: 0; должны вам помочь

Comment: Проще говоря, при разворачивании, контент в блоке всегда был прокручен к самому низу. При помощи CSS онли. Возможно так?

Comment: Только css - невозможно. js - возможно.

Comment: Я хотел заюзать css3 transition при раскрытии дерева, и чтобы был такой эффект. Жабаскрипт к сожалению не подойдет.

Comment: Если примерно такая ситуация, то сделать в подменю последние пункты видимыми раньше первых не выйдет http://jsbin.com/penavi/1/edit?html,css,output